# Reading rails text_field names with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Here is what I'm trying to do

```
<% form_for @color, :html => {:multipart => true, :name => "color_form"} do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :head_color %>
```

and I want to use this javascript

```
document.color_form.color[head_color].value;
```

javascript obviously doesn't like this and throws an error.  The problem is that I can't use text_field_tag.  How can I get javascript to read this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code acts as if the DOM treats `array_field[names]` in any sort of special way, making `document.color_form.color` an array. Nope, it's not quite that clever.

You can still access the field by name, though, using bracket notation.

```
document.color_form["color[head_color]"].value
```

Answer (score 0):

used `getElementById`,  duh... much easier